# Bash Array Manipulation

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix

I doing a project for a Unix/Linux class and have a few Arrays in another file, like this

All the arrays should store is a 1 or 0

```
    T1=( 1 1 1 1 1 )
    T2=( 1 1 1 1 1 )
    T3=( 1 1 1 1 1 )
    T4=( 1 1 1 1 1 )
    T5=( 1 1 1 1 1 )
```

However i'm having difficulty editing the arrays to 0 and making changes stick

```
    #!/bin/bash

    i=0

    for line in `cat JeopardyOut`
    do
        let i=i+1
        #Creating one big Array with all the values from the arrays file
        Array[i]=$line
    done

    cat JeopardyOut

    #Parsing the giant Array into the main 5 arrays I'm using
    createArray()
    {
    y=0
    for y in 0 1 2 3 4
    do
         for i in 2 3 4 5 6
         do
            #echo "${Array[i]}"
            T1[$y]=${Array[i]}
         done

         for i in 9 10 11 12 13
         do
            #echo "${Array[i]}"
            T2[$y]=${Array[i]}
         done

         for i in 16 17 18 19 20
         do
            #echo "${Array[i]}"
            T3[$y]=${Array[i]}
         done

         for i in 23 24 25 26 27
         do
            #echo "${Array[i]}"
            T4[$y]=${Array[i]}
         done

         for i in 30 31 32 33 34
         do
            #echo "${Array[i]}"
            T5[$y]=${Array[i]}
         done

    done
    }

    createArray

    ArrayNum=$1
    Index=$2
```

There's likely way better ways to do this, However this is what ended up working for me.

```
      #Changing the necessary indexes, this will be used by a completely 
      #different script 
      ChangeArray()
      {

       if [[ $ArrayNum == "1" ]]; then
           T1[ $Index ]=0
      elif [[ $ArrayNum == "2" ]]; then
           T2[ $Index ]=0
      elif [[ $ArrayNum == "3" ]]; then
           T3[ $Index ]=0
      elif [[ $ArrayNum == "4" ]]; then
           T4[ $Index ]=0
      elif [[ $ArrayNum == "5" ]]; then
           T5[ $Index ]=0
      else
            echo "Invalid Parameters"
       fi
  } 

 if [[ $ArrayNum -ne "" || $Index -ne "" ]]; then
    if [[ $ArrayNum == "5" && $Index == "5"]]; then
         reset
    else
         ChangeArray
    fi 
 fi
   # And the part that's likely at fault for my issue but don't know how I 
   # should fix it
   echo "T1=( ${T1[*]} )" > JeopardyOut
   echo "T2=( ${T2[*]} )" >> JeopardyOut
   echo "T3=( ${T3[*]} )" >> JeopardyOut
   echo "T4=( ${T4[*]} )" >> JeopardyOut
   echo "T5=( ${T5[*]} )" >> JeopardyOut

   cat JeopardyOut
```

Something is wrong with the way I am trying to edit the Arrays... 
While I can get any index of any of the arrays to 0, I do not know why the 1s I change to 0 turn back into 1 when I rerun the script.

PS. This is a basis class for Linux programming in Sierra, I don't really understand a lot of the bash script other than what I've learned through trial and error.

Comment: `bash` really isn't an ideal language for doing array manipulation; arrays are intended as a second level of quoting for passing arguments, not as a general-purpose data structure. Can you give an example of what `Array` would look like, and what the resulting `T` arrays should look like after calling `createArray`, though?

Comment: You need to go back to the beginning and get the solution to work for a single line in your file.  The for loop at the start makes no sense.  Try running just the for loop and echo at the values for $line ... you may be surprised what you get (this is assuming the file is in the format at top of question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Maybe this example can help you**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    #Creating one big Array with all the values from the arrays file
    Array+=(`grep -oP '\(\K(.+?)(?=\))' <<< "$line"`)
done < JeopardyOut

echo "Giant Array value: ${Array[@]}"

# Or you can clone the arrays in the file

i=0
while read -r line; do
    ((i++))
    eval "T$i=(`grep -oP '\(\K(.+?)(?=\))' <<< "$line"`)"
done < JeopardyOut

echo "This is the contents of array T1: ${T1[@]}"
echo "This is the contents of array T2: ${T2[@]}"
echo "This is the contents of array T3: ${T3[@]}"
echo "This is the contents of array T4: ${T4[@]}"
echo "This is the contents of array T5: ${T5[@]}"

# This can help you to make a new file
# I change some value to our arrays

T1[2]=0
T2[1]=true

# Now let's go to make a new arrays file

echo "T1=(${T1[@]})" > JeopardyOut2
echo "T2=(${T2[@]})" >> JeopardyOut2
echo "T3=(${T3[@]})" >> JeopardyOut2
echo "T4=(${T4[@]})" >> JeopardyOut2
echo "T5=(${T5[@]})" >> JeopardyOut2

echo "This is the content of JeopardyOut2:"

cat JeopardyOut2
```

**Output**

```
$ bash example
Giant Array value: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
This is the contents of array T1: 1 1 1 1 1
This is the contents of array T2: 1 1 1 1 1
This is the contents of array T3: 1 1 1 1 1
This is the contents of array T4: 1 1 1 1 1
This is the contents of array T5: 1 1 1 1 1
This is the content of JeopardyOut2:
T1=(1 1 0 1 1)
T2=(1 true 1 1 1)
T3=(1 1 1 1 1)
T4=(1 1 1 1 1)
T5=(1 1 1 1 1)
$
```

Comment: `eval` is almost certainly unnecessary here.

Comment: Thank God, and thank you, one long all night-er and you save my ass. I think I found the problem but fixing it was another story. I have a weak spot when it comes to expression. It'll take me some time to understand everything you did there but it was a big help. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't understand downvotation.

Comment: @chepner I must use eval because I can't assign the number to array name in another way.

Comment: Sure you can: stop using a loop to set the 5 variables.

Comment: The loop is forced because the arrays in the file can to be one or one hundred. If i want write everything manually i don't need of a script.